# como ajustar tamaño de imagen dentro de un contenedor de canvas en html5

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

estoy manejando imágenes con diferentes dimensiones en una web de ventas y me gustaría poder redimensionar automáticamente la imagen que el usuario sube, dentro de un canvas en javascript y html5 para luego mostrarlas sin que pierdan su relación original de alto por ancho, es decir si la imagen que carga una persona es de 600px de alto x 400px de ancho y en canvas establezco la altura en 300px entonces la imagen se redimensione de acuerdo a esta manteniendo la relación original, entonces quedaria de 300px de alto x 200px de ancho.

Comment: porfavor lee [ask].

Comment: En canvas puedes pintar una imagen utilizando el método drawImage() del contexto. Por ejemplo `ctx.drawImage( img, x, y ,w, h );` donde img es la imagen que quieres pintar, x e y representan las coordenadas de la esquina izquierda arriba de la imagen y w y h representan la anchura y la altura de la imagen. Para más detalles por favor lea esto: [Trabajar con imágenes en canvas](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/canvas/imagenes.php)

Comment: genial, gracias por la informacion proporcionada, me fue de gran utilidad!